# Image and bullets lose their active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

My `jQuery` slideshow has 4 slides and when it reaches the 4th one in the first full cycle the image and bullets lose their active class and it goes back to normal on it's second full cycle.

I had this working before I added the bullets functionality. I tried deleting but still it didn't work!

Update : add html/css code.

```js
var $slide = $(".slide");
  var $caption = $(".caption");
  var $bullet = $(".bullet");
  var currentSlide = 1;
  var slideSpeed = 6000;

  function slideBg() {
    var currentImg = $(".slide.active");
    var nextImg = currentImg.next();
    var currentBullet = $(".bullet.active");
    var nextBullet = currentBullet.next();
    var currentCaption = $(".caption.active");
    var nextCap = currentCaption.next();
      if (currentSlide >= $slide.length) {
        $("#img0").addClass("active");
        currentImg.removeClass("active");
        $("#0").addClass("active");
        currentBullet.removeClass("active");
        $("#cap0").addClass("active");
        currentCaption.removeClass("active");
        currentSlide = 1;
      }
      else {
        currentImg.removeClass("active");
        nextImg.addClass("active");
        currentBullet.removeClass("active");
        nextBullet.addClass("active");
        currentCaption.removeClass("active");
        nextCap.addClass("active");
        currentSlide++;
      }
    }


var timer = function() {
  interval = setInterval(function () {
    slideBg();
  }, slideSpeed);
  }
  timer();
```

```css
.slide {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 visibility: hidden!important;
 display: block!important;
  opacity: 0.5!important;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear!important;
}

.active {
 visibility: visible!important;
  opacity: 1!important;
 display: block!important;
}

.caption {
 z-index: 3;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 38%;
 left: 15%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;
 display: block;
 visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}
.bullet {
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 100%;
 margin-left: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.bullet.active {
 background-color: #143885;
 transform: scale(1.5);
}

.bullet:hover {
 background-color: #143885;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow" class="contentbox">
  <img src="img/bg1.jpg" id="img0" class="slide active"></img>
  <img src="img/bg2.jpg" id="img1" class="slide"></img>
  <img src="img/bg3.jpg" id="img2" class="slide"></img>
  <img src="img/bg4.jpg" id="img3" class="slide"></img>

  <div id="cap0" class="caption active">
   <h1><span>Our</span> Latest <span>event</span> is ready <span>now</span>!</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a sapien ac metus viverra suscipit. Maecenas viverra et orci eu tempor. Morbi pulvinar condimentum lorem, et luctus sapien finibus vel. Maecenas pharetra porta est, a suscipit metus sodales in. Phasellus placerat tellus vitae mollis molestie.</p>
   <button type="button" name="button">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div id="cap1" class="caption">
   <h1><span>Our</span> Second <span>event</span> is ready <span>now</span>!</h1>
   <p>Vivamus non sagittis ipsum, quis rhoncus ante. In aliquam ultrices nisi, a ultrices mi mattis ut. Nulla velit libero, tristique pretium euismod vel, euismod id justo. Pellentesque iaculis fringilla ex, ut tempor felis volutpat nec.</p>
   <button type="button" name="button">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div id="cap2" class="caption">
   <h1><span>Our</span> Third <span>event</span> is ready <span>now</span>!</h1>
   <p>Donec congue molestie auctor. Suspendisse maximus lorem id felis finibus ultrices. Curabitur eu scelerisque dui. Vivamus accumsan congue massa, et volutpat libero tincidunt vel.</p>
   <button type="button" name="button">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div id="cap3" class="caption">
   <h1><span>Our</span> Fourth <span>event</span> is ready <span>now</span>!</h1>
   <p>Morbi sit amet mauris sed mi convallis porta. Praesent urna sem, porta sed odio id, consequat convallis purus. Donec quis magna consectetur, ultrices nisi in, condimentum leo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus quam nisi,</p>
   <button type="button" name="button">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div id="bullets">
   <span id="0" class="bullet active"></span>
   <span id="1" class="bullet"></span>
   <span id="2" class="bullet"></span>
   <span id="3" class="bullet"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please share your `HTML` codes as well.

Comment: Done, Thanks for your concern!

Comment: You missed `currentBullet.removeClass("active");` if I'm right

Comment: @AtefMechken Do you have `CSS` as well, if yes please share that to.

Comment: @JoshuaK I added it still same thing probably i removed it accidently.

Comment: @Shiladitya Done!
thank you all for your replies :D

Comment: your code is overcomplicated! I simplified it a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/vabj0hab/

Comment: Applied your CSS after your edit: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/vabj0hab/1/)

Comment: @JoshuaK It works thanks <3 , I'm still i start with a simple code and as soon as I get a problem it gets over complicated.

Comment: @AtefMechken .Your last comment shows Done!. Did you resolve the issue or you added `CSS` that's why you mentioned Done!?

Comment: @Shiladitya Joshua's solution resolved my issue.

Comment: @AtefMechken .  Have a look into a solution https://jsfiddle.net/grqth07z/1/

Comment: @Shiladitya your code uses jQuery but you're not using it streight. That's bad coding style. Try to use jQuerys features if you use jQuery. It's a way better readable! Furthermore is your code also to complecated in somecases like the overflow of the slidecounter... and so on.